# Office display screen auto-updating content from live spreadsheet

Tags: excel, file, display, live

I have a 60" TV connected to a mini Desktop on the office network that I want to have display the content of a spreadsheet or similar 24/7.  We will be updating the source spreadsheet from multiple client machines so it needs to be unlocked for editing.

My first thought was to have a script refreshing a read only copy of the file on regular intervals but there has to be a more user friendly way. The source file information is in Excel format but I am not necessarily tied to Excel on the display screen.  Open to all suggestions including a completely different approach with different software / hardware.

Comment: Your spreadsheet presented on the screen could also have a script looking at a source spreadsheet in intervals, updating its content. That way you can always access the source and modify data. Personally I made a spreadsheet that everyone can access, it would write data to CSV and the presentation spreadsheet would update itself with these CSV-files. There are obviously more ways to do things.

Comment: For this to work, would the source file need to be a csv file or could it remain a .xls file?  I'm not sure I understand when you say that the source file would write data to CSV?  Would we need to constantly export the latest source save to .csv file or am I taking you up wrong?  Ideally, I want this to be a solution that involves a minimum amount of maintenance, something that once setup, takes care of itself.